# Pointing "any" domains to a specific Laravel path?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am currently developing a project where people can come into my Laravel project and create their own one-page website.

Now I would like to have them be to able to point their own custom domain to a specific Laravel route.

There's only one path that will "receive" all the domains, for example

[Customer 1]
have ABC.com

```
ABC.com -> point to -> mylaravelproject.com/route1
```

[Custom 2]
have DEF.com

```
DEF.com -> point to -> mylaravelproject.com/route1
```

And I will just let the code in Laravel route file detect the domain, and display the content dynamically

**/routes/web.php**

```
$thankyoupages = Thankyoupage::whereNotNull('domain')->get();
foreach( $thankyoupages as $ty ) {
    Route::group(['domain' => $ty->domain], function() use ($ty) {
        Route::get("/", function() use($ty) {
            $data = [
                "ty" => $ty,
                "pixels" => json_decode($ty->pixels)
            ];
            return view('thankyous.thankyoupage', $data);
        });
    });
}
```

My questions are:

[1] Are there any (easy) ways to achieve this?

[2] Do I have to alter Vhosts of Apache dynamically? or do I need reverse proxy?

[3] How to config the domain in order to achieve this? Just point A record to server's IP? or should I use CNAME?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

For handle dynamically domains in one laravel project I came to the following solution after a lot of searching and experimenting in one of my projects. It's not ideal you may impove on your own.

1. First all your domain must be added A record or CName in dns records
   from DNS managers. A record pointed to your server IP  works perfectly
2. Add your route list new group by domain example:

   ```
     Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function () {
     $url = Request::getHost();
     $full_url = url('/');
     Helper::domain($url, $full_url);
    // Your routes list ...  
     }
   ```

Also, we will need send dynamically domain name in diferent part of your application  for instance in controller. For that I added new helper function to Helper class:

```
class Helper
{
    public static $domain;
    public static $full_domain;
    public static $autoload_static_data;
    public static $position;
    public static function domain($domain,$full_domain)
        {
            
            Helper::$domain=$domain;
            Helper::$full_domain=$full_domain;
            $domain_info=domain_info();
            
            if ($full_domain==env('APP_URL') || $full_domain==env('APP_URL_WITHOUT_WWW')) {
                return true;
            }
            if ($domain==env('APP_PROTOCOLESS_URL') || str_replace('www.','',$domain)==env('APP_PROTOCOLESS_URL')) {
                return true;
            }
        
        
                    
            $domain=str_replace('www.','',$domain);
            Helper::$domain=$domain;
            if (!Cache::has(Helper::$domain)) {
    
                $value = Cache::remember(Helper::$domain, 600,function () {
                    $data=\App\Domain::where('domain',Helper::$domain)->where('status',1)->first();
                    if (empty($data)) {
                        abort(404);//or you can make custom 404 page
                    }
                    
                    $info['domain_id']=$data->id;
                    $info['user_id']=$data->user_id;
                    $info['domain_name']= Helper::$domain;
                    $info['full_domain']= Helper::$full_domain;
                    $info['plan']=json_decode($data->information);
                    return $info;
                });
            }
    
        }
```

You must save all your domain in database. In my case it was domains table and Domain model. You can verify domain and get all related information separately by domain.

Inside your server to handle all your domains in single webroot folder you can use ServerAlias * (wildcards)

Nginx in your configuration inside server block for server_name you can use regex

`If you do not understand or have additional questions, you can ask via comment`

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to follow your guide but currently stuck at SSL. I cannot access my new domain that's pointed to the Laravel project, got an error: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Requesting * wildcard domain from Let's Encrypt is no luck. Any suggestion please? thank you in advance 